# Convert LastNotEmpty Query to Member

Tags: sql-server, ssas, sql-server-2014, mdx

I would like to report the state of data availability resp. the max date specific measure(groups) have data loaded. This is a functionality I would then try to incorporate into each report. In theory each measure could have another "last member with data" in the date dimension however it is OK for the moment to simplify that to one measure per measure group or the max for the whole measure group.

I have written an MDX query which gives me the relevant answer. However to leverage easier maintenance I am striving to incorporate that information as a calculated member into the cube itself. Using MDX only every leap year or so I did not successfully manage to convert the query into a calculated member definition.

```
// Repro-Query on Adventure Works
// with Adventure Works 2012 EE result should be "July 31, 2008"
// contrasted to last date in date dimension which is "December 31,2010
WITH Member [Measures].[Data Availability] AS 
                [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember.Name
SELECT
    {       
        [Measures].[Data Availability]
    } ON COLUMNS
FROM
    [Adventure Works]
WHERE
{
    TAIL(
        FILTER
        (
            [Date].[Date].Members,
            [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] >0
        )
    ,1 
    )
}
```

Result shoud be the same as in the query but encapsulated within one calculated measure statement. Remember I don't need the value of the measure but just the name of the last dimension element with data in the date dimension.

Regarding code it should be something like this:

```
WITH Member [Measures].[Data Availability] AS 
                <your great translation to a member > 
SELECT
    {       
        [Measures].[Data Availability]
    } ON COLUMNS
FROM
    [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Feel free to suggest different approaches to get the answer to the problem like better performing ways to calculate the last member with data.

Comment: Sample data and expected output would make this question much easier to answer

Comment: @GuidoG Well sample data is the Adventure Works Cube provided by MSFT (https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/releases/tag/adventureworks-analysis-services). For expected output see screenshot. But you could answer the question with your cube as well as it is kind of generic.

Comment: sorry, not much people here will download and use that just for answering your question. good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the great question and for using Adventure Works. Despite what some commenters say, that’s a great way to get an answer here.

Try this. The `Tail` function returns a set so `.Item(0).Item(0)` turns it into a member by choosing the first tuple and first member.

```
WITH Member [Measures].[Data Availability] AS 
    TAIL(
        FILTER
        (
            [Date].[Date].Members,
            [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount] >0
        )
    ,1 
    ).Item(0).Item(0).Name
SELECT
    {       
        [Measures].[Data Availability]
    } ON COLUMNS
FROM
    [Adventure Works]
```

Comment: Wow my first question on MDX here on StackOverflow (I think) and I get an answer from an SSAS MVP! This rocks! I was so close experimenting with .Item(0) but never thought of doing another Item(0). This proves that I did not understand this thoroughly and anyway if I would have it would be challenging to keep the knowledge over the years only applying it every leap year or so. Funny thing is I was just asked what I think about MDX in an interview today and mentioned that question. Bottomline: MDX is fine but challenging if you don't practice regularly.